# How to test an item added to Visual Studio Code status bar using automated tests?

Tags: visual-studio-code, testing, automated-tests, vscode-extensions

How to test that item was added into vscode status bar?

Im writing extension for Visual Studio Code and this extension add some item into status bar. How can i test what is inside status bar item and interact with this item? Try looking on same examples on web but no examples or tips how to do it or how to test it another way.

Thanks for tips! :)

Comment: mock the function that creates a status bar item and test if it has been called with the correct arguments

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for tip, but this is only one think. I basically need to test user scenario like check status bar item content than click on it, select new profile and check that this item was changed in text and color.

Comment: you have no control over the VSC API, if the API does not do what it is supposed to do VSC has a problem and not you, expect the API to behave as documented, so mock the API functions and control if it is called with the correct arguments and you can also return a picked item if needed. If there is a command attached to a status button expect it will be called when clicked

Comment: @rioV8 Yep thats look like a solution think that i ended with :) Im just curious that there is no e2e testing or similar tools to test interactions of users with extensions. So nobody do e2E testing on vscode extensions? :-O Thats strange. I get it that unit testing and mocking is sufficient in this case, but use case testing make also big sense for me, it case that is a complex extension ... But thanks for responses!